# Find and list files containing numbers in names with reg exp

Tags: regex, sed, grep, numbers, filenames

I have a file with output of ls -lR command. How can find in it and list the names of files that contain number/nunbers in filename?

The part of output file:

```
/home/guest/tmp:
total 48
drwxrwxr-x. 3 guest guest 4096 Nov  9 17:26 dir1
drwxrwxr-x. 2 guest guest 4096 Nov  9 15:58 dir13
-rw-rw-r--. 1 guest guest  280 Nov  9 16:59 file1.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 guest guest  334 Nov  9 16:55 file2.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 guest guest  556 Nov  9 17:33 file3.txt
-rw-r--rw-. 1 root  root  2088 Nov 15 13:33 log
-rw-rw-r--. 1 guest guest    0 Nov 21 16:33 log2
-rw-rw-r--. 1 guest guest    0 Nov 21 16:34 log3
-rw-rw-r--. 1 guest guest  319 Nov 20 16:05 rx_tx_bytes.txt
```

I used for that

```
cat <path to lsoutput> | grep '^-' | grep -e '[0-9]\+\.' | awk '{print $9}'
```

This gives the correct result, but it doesn't list files with numbers in name that have no extensions. For example, filenames log2 and log3 should appear in list too, but they didn't. What condition should I add to catch such files too?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe replace `grep '^-' | grep -e '[0-9]\+\.'` with `grep -E '^-.*[0-9](\.[[:alnum:]]+)?$'`? Note your approach will fail if the file names contain spaces

Comment: Yes, this works for my case! Thanks. So as I understand the main mechanism of searching files w/o extension is `(\.[[:alnum:]]+)?$`, right?

Comment: `(\.[[:alnum:]]+)?` is an optional capturing group that matches one or zero sequences of the `.` and 1+ alnum chars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may "quick-fix" your code by replacing `grep '^-' | grep -e '[0-9]\+\.'` with `grep -E '^-.*[0-9](\.[[:alnum:]]+)?$'`.

Here, `(\.[[:alnum:]]+)?` is an optional capturing group that matches one or zero sequences of the `.` and 1+ alphanumeric chars.

Note your approach will fail if the file names contain spaces.

With GNU `find` you may use a safer command:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/.*[0-9](\.[[:alnum:]]+)?$'
```

The regex passed to `find` must match the whole string, hence the initial `.*/` that matches any 0+ chars up to the last `/`, any 0+ chars, a digit, an optional sequence of `.` + one or more alphanumeric chars and the end of the string (here, file path).